# Cannot skip tokens on partial JSON

Tags: c#

I am using MicrosoftSpatialGeoJsonConverter and got excpetion in reader.Skip() `Cannot skip tokens on partial JSON. Either get the whole payload and create a Utf8JsonReader instance where isFinalBlock is true or call TrySkip.'`

sample code for Read

```
if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.Null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            string type = default;
            double? longitude = default;
            double? latitude = default;

            while (reader.Read() && reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndObject)
            {
                string propertyName = reader.GetString();

                reader.Read();
                if (string.Equals(TypePropertyName, propertyName, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                {
                    type = reader.GetString();
                }
                else if (string.Equals(CoordinatesPropertyName, propertyName, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                {

                    // Longitude
                    reader.Read();
                    longitude = reader.GetDouble();

                    // Latitude
                    reader.Read();
                    latitude = reader.GetDouble();

                    // Skip the rest.
                    do
                    {
                        reader.Read();
                    } while (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndArray);
                }
                else
                {
                    reader.Skip();
                }
            }

            return GeographyPoint.Create(latitude.Value, longitude.Value);
        }
```

I can see bytesConsumed number and TokenStartIndex value, how can it find which character is not valid ? examinating response all looks ok, it is very long so can't paste it here

```
type Point coordinates -73.87913 42.82626 crs type properties name EPSG:4326 -->this one throws error

type Point coordinates -0.09761 51.50495 crs type properties name EPSG:4326 -->this one works
```

Comment: Why do you think it's an invalid character? Did you check the json with a viewer that detects not printable characters? Can you throw it into a 3rd party json validator? If it very long, it easy to miss a bracket somewhere.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods what might be other reason for this exception ?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the input. Can you "mock" some input and test your code? Just to see if this fails on just any json input with the same error or this specific input, only?

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods if tails only for specifict, how can i check what is the value the converter is trying to skip ?

Comment: Either step it through in the debugger (set a breakpoint in the else block) or add logging. Maybe do both.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods but how can i get what string the reader is trying to skip ?

Comment: Make use of the debugger and the watch windows. You should be able to at least get some index into the string, then you can investigate further. You also could use try/catch and dump what is left in the reader if possible ... )

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods updated question with sample data